# Telethon reply to the last channel post only

Tags: arrays, telethon

I have coded a small script which replies to channel posts. It works, but I want it to post only to the last channel post if multiple posts have been made in a short time (for example 3 posts in 5-10 seconds). I want it to post only to the last post of the 3.

This is my code so far:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(CHANNEL))
async def main(event):
    if -100123456789 == event.chat_id:
        await client.send_message(event.chat_id, 'my_message', comment_to=event.id)
```

I tried out some stuff like with append() but it still replies to all posts. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to start a new task when the first message arrives, and not do so when subsequent ones arrive.

```py
import asyncio

reply_task = None
reply_to = None

COOLDOWN = 20  # seconds

async def do_reply():
    global reply_task, reply_to
    await asyncio.sleep(COOLDOWN)
    await client.send_message(reply_to.chat_id, 'my_message', comment_to=reply_to.id)
    reply_task = None

@client.on(events.NewMessage(CHANNEL))
async def main(event):
    global reply_task, reply_to

    if reply_task is None:
        reply_task = asyncio.create_task(do_reply())
    
    reply_to = event
```

When a message arrives, if there's no task, a new one will be made. The last event will be saved in a variable.

When the spawned task completes the sleep, it will send the message to whichever event was last, and set the current task to `None` so a new one can be started.

This does not handle multiple groups correctly. It also does not correctly handle exceptions. It also does not worry with proper cancellation of the task. This is only the skeleton of an idea.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me and I've learned a lot!